# What's the best way to block on a GPU operation in TensorFlow's Eager mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, timing

I would like to know the recommended way to wait for a GPU operation to complete in TensorFlow Eager mode.

Operations that are located on a GPU device appear to execute asynchronously (I could not find this in the TensorFlow documentation, but it's consistent with behavior). This is important, for example, when timing GPU ops using `time.time()`*, since we need to make sure the ops are completed before logging the end time.

The only way I could find to ensure a GPU operation has been executed is to explicitly copy (some of) the output data to the CPU.

For example (assuming all operations are carried out on the GPU):

```py
t0 = time.time()
result = f(input_tensor)  # carry out some operations on the input
_ = result[0].numpy()  # copies a single element of the output tensor to the CPU
t1 = time.time()
print("runtime =", t1 - t0)
```

Since copying data to the CPU incurs some overhead, it would be nice to have a way to ensure the GPU has finished executing without copying. Is there such a way? Perhaps something like JAX's [block_until_ready()](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async_dispatch.html)?

*I realize that using `time.time()` may not be the best way to time GPU operations in Eager mode.

Comment: Would returning just a single element result[0][0,0,0...] work?

Comment: This is what I meant by "copies a single element". Have edited to clarify. I guess I don't know how much overhead a single-element copy incurs. I'm assuming there are some setup costs for the copy, so I'm specifically looking for a solution that copies no data at all.

Comment: I think you can just compute `tf.identity(your_op)` Now the identity operation will depend on `your_op`, so compute it and `your_op` must be computed.

Comment: @DavidParks Just tried that, but it doesn't work. Presumably the identity op gets "executed" on the GPU too, so this is still asynchronous.

Comment: You might want to check out the tensorflow profiler breakdown: https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d

Comment: @DavidParks That's a handy blog post, but it doesn't explain how to profile in Eager mode. See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56693208/11666760)!